# How do I get the size of an int*?

Tags: c++

I want to get the size of an integer array in C++. If a method takes in an int* how do I get the size of that value?

```
int myMethod(int* values)
{
     values.size();

}
```

this give compilation errors

Comment: Do you mean you've passed in an array, and want to find its length ?

Comment: @nos yes that is correct

Comment: You cannot, size needs to be passed as parameter. Better use `std::vector <int>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could get the size of of a pointer to an integer with `sizeof(int*)`.

However, given a pointer value, there is no portable way (in C or C++) to get the dynamic -runtime- size of the pointed memory zone (in heap or elsewhere).

A general advice is to avoid raw pointers when possible: use [smart pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) (from [`<memory>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) header) and [standard C++ containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) (e.g. [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) from `<vector>`)

So if you declared `std::vector<int> values;` you could get the vector size with `values.size();`